# Update many records from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm attempting to use a class method to update many records that I've modified and stored in an array; I've cobbled together a way to do this but it seems hackey and uses the update method which I read is depreciated.

```
def big_update
  items = Table.all
  saves=[]

  items.each do |item|
    item.value = rand(10)
    saves << item.as_json
  end

  saves = Hash[*saves.map{ |p| [p["id"], p] }.flatten]
  self.update(saves.keys, saves.values)
end
```

The key is that I'm looking to only hit the database once to save all of these, rather than hitting it with each iteration.

I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this so any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to set the `value` column to a random number between 0 and 9 (inclusive) and leave everything else alone?

Comment: @muistooshort for all intents and purposes, yes.  Really I'm grabbing values from spreadsheets, transforming them and then using the result to update the table but I figured this example case would be much easier to read.

Comment: If you already have the data in memory (i.e. you've parsed some spreadsheets) then  what you have is pretty much what it will look like. If the data is already in the database then you could do a single SQL update and use the database's `rand` or `random` function. You could also mangle the spreadsheets into a CSV, import the CSV using the database's CSV import tools, and the do an UPDATE to set the random numbers. So depends on how much data you have and where it is. Hope this bit of handwaving helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's some additional nuance with what you're doing but if you just want to update the `value` field to a random number within a class you can do it like this:

```
def big_update
  Table.all.each do |table|
    table.update(value: rand(10))
  end
end
```

Comment: That would basically work, the key goal (which I added to my question once I saw your answer) is that I don't want to hit the database with each iteration for performance considerations.

Comment: @neanderslob In that case what you've got there is, in essence, the best AR implementation of that type of query. They've added new functionality to Rails 6, which is likely what you're looking for, in a method called `#upsert_all`. If you are on Rails 6 and would like me to edit my answer with that solution, feel free to let me know.